# How can I be a "useful" community member?

Tags: discussion

To the beginning I have to admit that this is not my first account on stackoverflow. It's my fourth.

I really love stackoverflow; full of helpful answers and competent members and I want to be a part of it.
My problem is, that my asked question got flagged - for duplicates, off topic and so on. I always googled before I asked my question and looked at the "similar questions" here on stackoverflow but nothing fitted my question.

With the time all my last accounts got "banned" (not allowed to ask anything until I improved my questions).
I want to do it right this time; I want to be a helpful part of this community.

And so I look for some tips (or even a guide?) how I can get started here.

Thank you and kind regards!

Comment: It's usually enough to read **all of the advice** that was given to you, before your previous accounts got banned, how you were wrong and what can be done to improve.

Comment: If you're still struggling try to spend more time reading than writing, get a feel for how successful users are doing it before you jump back in.

Comment: And stop creating new accounts.

Comment: All of the guidelines can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You are probably doing the same mistake here, as you did with your previous account's questions: Low effort on research. That's why I downvoted your question here.

Comment: As much as I hate to add insult to injury, there is a bitter irony to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *can* be difficult to find existing questions on the site that answer a question you might have, that's true; I can sympathize with you there. I don't have any source links to provide, but I've often read that you should try *several times* to find the answer you seek before asking it on Stack Overflow. To quote loosely, "search for an answer for **days** before even considering pressing the 'Ask a Question' button".

As for improving the quality of the questions you *do* ask, take a look at high-voted *recent* questions and how they are written. I say *recent*, because many of the highest-voted questions on the site are from long ago, and, if asked today, would be closed and downvoted into oblivion.

Further, take a look at the Help Center, specifically the [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link. Adding details about your current code, what outcome (or error) you're getting, what outcome you *expect* to get, and listing some things you've tried are all useful pieces of information. Always strive to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem, whenever possible.